# How to download files with time-based bandwidth limitations?

Tags: windows, bandwidth, download-manager

I have huge files (15 Gb) to download from a provider which asks me to not download these files during buisness hours.

I've tried using FlashGet, or Free Download Manager, but I can't schedule bandwidth limitations on any of them.

So, as the title states, how can I download these files with respect for bandwidth limitations expressed by this provider ?

Comment: "not during business hours" usually means: "do not exceed our own bandwidth". so, i guess that if you throttle your downloader you can download the thing over days. on the other hand: such a huge file takes quite some time and thus you will have to download it in pieces / chunks.

Comment: @akira no here, it is explicitely asked to limit bandwidth during work hours

Comment: yah, but that does not mean that you can't download it at all. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39218/throttle-the-download-speed-of-wget-or-curl-while-downloading ... most likely the process will timeout (their server will cut you off). luckily you can --continue with wget if their servers supports "range-requests".

Answer (score 0):

looking at comments rang a bell for me. My answer will be to schedule a cycle like this:

1. schedule wget to start past the business hours.
2. schedule to kill wget Once the business ours are about to start. you may do that using pskill from sysinternals
3. schedule wget to start with bandwith limit on business ours
4. schedule pskill to kill that once the business ours are about to be over
5. restart the cycle until your file is complete